# how to unstack the pandas dataframe to get the number of count

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have the following data frame. I am trying to pivot the data frame.

```
Department          Manager_Rank   
Electronics         A1
Electronics         A2
Electronics         A3
Electronics         A4
Electronics         B1
Electronics         B2
Electronics         B3
Electronics         B4

Desired:
Department         A1-A4    B1-B4
Electronics        4          4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform` with `join` and `take` to construct series use for both `columns` and `values` of `pd.crosstab`

```
cols = (df.groupby(df.Manager_Rank.str[0]).Manager_Rank
                                          .transform(lambda x: '-'.join(x.take([0,-1]))))

df_final = pd.crosstab(index=df.Department, columns=cols)

Out[506]:
Manager_Rank  A1-A4  B1-B4
Department
Electronics       4      4
```

Comment: interesting and nice usage of `take` :-)

Comment: This is not working when there is multiple departments. strngely

Comment: @gannu: could you share a sample which causes it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

We can slice the first letter of Rank, then use `transform` create the column key, and do it with `groupby` `size` + `unstack`

```
g = df.groupby(df.Manager_Rank.str[0])['Manager_Rank']
s = df.groupby([df.Department, g.transform('first') + '_' + g.transform('last')]).size().unstack()
Out[196]: 
Manager_Rank  A1_A4  B1_B4
Department                
Electronics       4      4
```